# Type Cast Map[String, Object] to Map[String, String]

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-collections

I am new to scala and I see the following exception:

```
value mapValues is not a member of java.util.Map[String,Object]
[error]  headers = Option(data).map(_.mapValues(_.toString)).getOrElse(Map()),
[error]                               ^
```

Here is the snippet:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def toMessage(properties: AMQP.BasicProperties, body: Array[Byte]): Message = {
    Message (
        headers = Option(data).map(_.mapValues(_.toString)).getOrElse(Map())) <<----- THIS LINE HAS PROBLEMS!!!
}
```

I know that the datatype of `headers` is `Map[String, String]` and that of `data` is `Map<String, Object>`. How I can type cast this to resolve the issue?

**UPDATE**

Made the changes suggested by Alvaro and Tanjin. Now i get this exception:

Now i get:

```
[error]  found   : Map[String,String] (in scala.collection)
[error]  required: Map[String,String] (in scala.collection.immutable)
[error]       headers         = Option(properties.getHeaders).map(_.asScala.mapValues(_.toString)).getOrElse(Map())
[error]                                                                                                     ^
```

Comment: `getOrElse(collection.immutable.Map())`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `data` is of type `java.util.Map[...]`, but the `mapValues` method is on `scala.collection.Map[...]`. So you need to transform it using the `.asScala` method (brought implicitly by the `JavaConverters` import:

```
Option(data).map(_.asScala.toMap.mapValues(_.toString)).getOrElse(Map.empty))
```

Also add a `.toMap` since `.asScala` will return a mutable `Map`... `.toMap` makes it immutable.

Comment: What are your imports? are you importing a mutable version of scala's Map by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

How does this work?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def toMessage(properties: AMQP.BasicProperties, body: Array[Byte]): Message = {
  Message (
    headers = Option(data)
      .map(_.asScala)
      .getOrElse(collection.immutable.Map.empty)
      .mapValues(_.toString)
}
```